# Make NSOperationQueue synchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

How can I make NSOperationQueue synchronous? I did tried this by subclassing NSOperation and setting "setMaxConcurrentOperationCount" to 1. And also adding dependencies on previous operations using "addDependency" method.

Adding Code:

```
if(!operationQueue)
{
    operationQueue = [[MyQueue alloc] init];
}
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
UploadFileOperation *uploadFileOperation = [[UploadFileOperation alloc] initWithObject:someObject];
[operationQueue addOperation:uploadFileOperation];
```

Now when log the upload progress for two files it shows that both the files are uploading at the same time. Like this:
File1 - 17.647026% Uploaded
File1 - 18.352907% Uploaded
File2 - 0.870381% Uploaded
File2 - 1.740762% Uploaded
File2 - 2.611142% Uploaded
File2 - 3.481523% Uploaded
File1 - 19.058788% Uploaded

Edit 2:
This is how I implemented NSOperation main method:

```
- (void)main {
@autoreleasepool {
    if(self.isCancelled)
    {
        return;
    }

    [[[NetworkManager alloc] init] uploadFileToAmazon:someURL WithRequestType:networkRequestType WithCompletion:^(NetworkRequestType _networkRequestType, id response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
       if(uploadFileDelegate && [uploadFileDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fileUploaded:)])
       {
           [uploadClipDelegate fileUploaded:response];
       }
    }];
}
}
```

I'm also using "[AFAmazonS3Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Manager)" for uploading files in "uploadFileToAmazon".

Comment: No subclassing needed. Simply set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property of the operation queue to 1.

Comment: @rmaddy: I did. But it does not work either.

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code so we can see what you are actually doing. And explain how you know that your operations are not synchronous.

Comment: @rmaddy: I've edited my question with some code.

Comment: Perhaps it is how your operation is implemented. Update your question with your `UploadFileOperation main` method.

Comment: Ok Alright. I'll edit again. A quick question though. My upload process is async. How can I make new uploads wait until I finish current uploads. I'm using AFNetworking.

Comment: @rmaddy: I've added main method.

Comment: A synchronous operation queue will run the next operation when the `main` method of the previous operation is finished. The `main` operation of your upload operation will return long before the upload is complete because the upload is being done on another background thread. You need to find a way to do the upload synchronously or use a semaphore to prevent `main` from returning before the upload is complete.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try using semaphore.